# Access my camera from the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, router, camera

I bought a camera put it inside my home to watch over my dog when I m not there. So far it's only visible on the local network, so when I m connected to wifi, using any device I can view camera/move camera/speak to my device/listen to the other side of device all works great.

Since I m renting a modem from a service provider, they won't let me have the admin password but they would make a configuration change like open ports for camera or whatever is needed. For anyone who previously configured anything, this would be very frustrating experience to tell someone to try something and you don't even know what you're trying at first (yes it's my first configuring camera to be streamed to internet).

I really want to avoid this if possible, I'd rather go another route like how teamviewer does, bypassing the router all together. I always have at least my computer connected to wifi when I m not at home, so I can install whatever in there to be able to let my cellphone/ipad in when I m away if need be. Connecting with teamview is ok but the picture is really blurry and everything is super slow. My connection is not though.

What are my options here really? What can I do to be able to look at my dog when I m away?

Comment: There are camera systems that don't need port forwarding rules.  Lorex for example has such a system.  It works by connecting to Lorex's server with an outgoing connection, your phone then connects via that server instead of directly.

Comment: what kinda camera?

Comment: Camera is hoo too camera https://www.amazon.com/HooToo-HT-IP211HDP-Security-Surveillance-Camera/dp/B01CKYD4YM

Answer (score 0):

If you ISP supports IPv6 then you might be able to connect your phone to an IPv6 broker and therefor bypass the router.

If they don't then you are left with VPN option, then again you can go two ways.

1. Setup up a VPN server at home and have you ISP do the port forwarding to allow you to connect the phone to VPN. (This is only good if your ISP provides dedicated IP or static IP)
2. Setup a VPN server in the Cloud and connect both your house and your phone.

Once VPN connection is established you will be able to connect to the camera internal LAN ip.

Answer (score 0):

Just get your ISP to forward the port to a static or reserved IP in your LAN and make sure your camera has that IP - a static or reserved address will always be given to the same device.

It will be much simpler than trying to find a much more complicated method that your device probably doesn't support or will mean you installing additional hardware (another computer) to load some software on to do the NAT bypassing... a waste of a device, electricity and your effort.

P.s. I've no idea why your ISP make you "rent" a device and not be able to configure basic things like port forwarding at least... if I knew my ISP would do this I'd be running a mile.